# Git push: "Everything up to date" even though changes have been committed

Tags: git

Disclaimer: I'm new to git, and it hasn't been a gentle learning process.

After I cloned a repository, I did the following:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/my_branch
git checkout my_branch
```

Then I made a few changes to my_file.txt and attempted to commit and push the changes:

```
git add my_file.txt
git commit -m "made some changes to my_file.txt"
git push
```

Unfortunately, every time I push I get the following message:

```
Everything up-to-date
```

even though I committed my changes. Does anyone know a fix for this?

Comment: please share the last commit of your branch and branch on the repository. Also, share git status logs.

Answer (score 2):

Hadn't set up my username with git, so it wasn't recognizing me. Was able to fix it with the following commands:

```
git config --global user.name "Name"
git config --global user.email "Email"
```

Comment: I can assure you, this has nothing to do with an "Everything up-to-date" message. It influences only how your commits are represented (author).

Answer (score 1):

Check the result of `git status`, and `git branch -avv` in order to see the state of your current branch compared to its upstream counterpart.

A better approach, when using [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#git-checkout-emgitcheckoutemltbranchgt), would be:

```
git checkout -B my_branch --track origin/my_branch
# add, commit
git push
```